# SQL Server - sum calculation from dynamic number of previous rows

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sum

I have that kind of data set.

```
ID  A   B
-----------
1    5  20 
2    4  20
3   14  20
4    4  20
5   20  30
6   15  30
7   10  30
8    6  30
9    4  30
10  10  30
```

My task is to sum the values from column A until there are not greater than value in column B using ID order. (Every time the value in B is different I start new calculation)

I need to do it in two ways:

First:

In case the running sum of the values from A column becomes greater than value in column B I need to split the current value in A column to 2 rows.

In the first row it will be the same ID and A value will be the difference between B column and previous SUM(A).

In the second row will the same ID the difference between original A value and value from previous row.

Look at the example:

```
ID  A   B  SumA SumA_ID
------------------------
1    5  20  20  1
2    4  20  20  1
3   11  20  20  1
3    3  20   7  2
4    4  20   7  2
5   20  30  30  1
6   10  30  30  1
6    5  30  30  2
7   10  30  30  2
8    6  30  30  2
9    4  30  30  2
10   5  30  30  2
10   5  30   5  3
```

Second:

Each time the current sum A is greater than the current value of B, I start to sum up again

```
ID  A   B  SumA SumA_ID
------------------------
1    5  20   9  1
2    4  20   9  1
3   14  20  19  2
4    4  20  19  2
5   20  30  20  1
6   15  30  25  2
7   10  30  25  2
8    6  30  20  3
9    4  30  20  3
10  10  30  20  3
```

As the data set is quite big I prefer not to use loops.

Can you suggest the most optimized way to do this in SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: Formatting your sample data would be *really* helpful.

Comment: I hope it's better now.